# I want to get the component inside the region? Is there any way?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

I am trying to create a page usign coreservices. I require to change the component inside the region. Is there any way I can do that ?[image]

Comment: At a guess, page contains a collection of regions, which then contains a collection of regions AND components (regions can have sub regions). This should indeed be available, you may need to play around. The code you posted is just getting pages where a component is used... have you tried looking inside the data object yet?

Comment: @NunoLinhares  Thanks for your response. I am able to get it now.

Comment: Can you post your code and solution as an answer? This will help others.